# MySql query insert statement

Tags: mysql, insert, key

Not sure why but it gives me an error of duplicate entry for primary when i try to execute the insert statement to creditcard table. My primary key is cardNumber, foreign key is email (taken from user table). The insert statement is shown below.

```
INSERT INTO CreditCard (email) SELECT email FROM User;
INSERT INTO CreditCard (cardNumber, name, cvv, expiryMonth, expiryyear) 
VALUES('3345678902345678','alicia','444','08','2015'); 
INSERT INTO CreditCard (cardNumber, name, cvv, expiryMonth, expiryyear)
VALUES('2345678902222278','javier','442','01','2015');
INSERT INTO CreditCard (cardNumber, name, cvv, expiryMonth, expiryyear) 
VALUES('2111678902345678','eddy','344','02','2015');
INSERT INTO CreditCard (cardNumber, name, cvv, expiryMonth, expiryyear) 
VALUES('1111678902345678','vanessa','224','01','2015');
INSERT INTO CreditCard (cardNumber, name, cvv, expiryMonth, expiryyear)    
VALUES('7777778902345678','aaron','400','03','2015');
```

The create table for creditcard and user:

```
CREATE TABLE CreditCard
(
cardNumber CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
cvv CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
expiryMonth INT NOT NULL,
expiryYear INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(cardNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES User(email) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE User
(
email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(email)
);
```

Comment: The first ```INSERT INTO CreditCard (email) SELECT email FROM User;```is trying to insert rows, only providing email column.

Comment: In addition, are you sure you want to be storing unencrypted credit card numbers? See e.g. [this post on security.se](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/storing-credit-card-numbers).